# Annotated setters that return class insance

Tags: java, annotations

For some time now I have been bothered by the lack of fluent interface setters. I am aware of Lomboks system however the generated functions still return a void. Would it be possible/and how to make a setter to return its class instance? Thanks

Comment: https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/experimental/Accessors#chain()

Comment: For any class of yours, and for any superclass of any of your subclasses, you're free to add setters that return a copy of their object.  If there are name conflicts with existing setters, you'll have to pick an alternate name, but you can generally build up your own fluent interfaces on top of most any object in Java.  And then there's Lombok and other frameworks that can generalize the idea.  Or switch to Kotlin, which gives you a more powerful system for extending objects only way you wantl.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer solved with [Accessors](https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/experimental/Accessors#chain()).

```
@Accessor(chain=true)
```

Over any class which you'd like to have chained.